# How to not let Sidebar scroll again when reach near footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found a jQuery code [online](https://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/) and used it for my sidebar scrolling.

Right now, it works but I have a problem that whenever my sidebar reaches below the page, it continues to expand and allows me to continue scrolling down.

I want it to kinda stop scrolling down when it reaches the footer. Any ideas on how to do that?

Here is the current code below:

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $(".my-sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```